# Google Sheets: Rounding DateTime Cell to Nearest 15 Mintutes

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a formula that I could use to round a date time cell up or down (1/10/2022 15:17:02) to the nearest 15 minute interval? I've tried MROUND but since the date time field is in a weird format, I can't quite figure out how to get that to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems to work for me, example here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Hq2pep92vmPQ8kPiThNUod7nsFZopMuOAFNcLCdkJcM/edit?usp=sharing

Using `=mround(A2,"00:15")` to round, `=floor(A2,"00:15")` to round down, and `=ceiling(A2,"00:15")` to round up.

Perhaps you forgot to format the end result back as a Date Time itself?

See more examples here: https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/round-round-up-round-down-hour-minute-second-in-google-sheets/

Comment: That did the trick! Is there a way to choose between rounding up and down?

Comment: Awesome!  Sure, just added those in the doc too.  Use CEILING() for rounding up, and FLOOR() for rounding down.  Just make sure to format the end result as well.

Answer (score 2):

you can use round to round down

```
=round(a1*96)/96
```

or ceiling to round up

```
=ceiling(a1*96)/96
```

with date time fields in Sheets the date is treated like a whole number and the time like a fractional part.

so if you want to round to 15 mins - there are `24 * 4 = 96` lots of 15 minutes in one day.  so multiply the date by 96, then round, then divide by 96 should do the trick.

Comment: What does the 96 do?

Comment: Is there a way I could choose between rounding up and down?